# select max and min from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have two tables that contain dates. I want to query the max and min dates from both tables. I know the line below will give me the max and min dates for one table.

```
 select max(dtTime), min(dtTime) from tableOne
```

What I want to do is get the min of the two max dates from table one and two & the max of the two min dates from the table. Please see the example below.

```
           TableOne       TableTwo
 Max Date  6-June-2000    23-June-2002
 Min Date  10-Jan-1980    15-Feb-1982
```

Result I would like returned,

```
Max Date = 6-June-2000
Min Date = 15-Feb-1982
```

Comment: Returned from what - are you writing a stored procedure, a function in code that displays something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION, and then select minimum from max values and max from minimum values:

```
SELECT min(mx), max(mn) 
FROM (
      SELECT max(dtTime) AS `mx`, min(dtTime) AS `mn` FROM tableOne
      UNION
      SELECT max(dtTime) AS `mx`, min(dtTime) AS `mn` FROM tablTow
     ) AS t1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select max(t1.dtTime), min(t2.dtTime) from tableOne as t1, tableTwo as t2
```